# How to pass URL query string parameters without predefining in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is there a way not define the URL Query string parameters in both Method Request and Integration Request and pass the query string to HTTP Proxy?

For example, in case of https://{api id}-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test/user?start=1&end=10

Query string 
1. start
2. end

If I put URL Query string parameters in Method request and Integration request then I'm able to get both query strings. However, if I don't add them and make a request in postman then in the back end I'm not getting both query strings.

I want to get query strings without defining in Method Request and Integration Request. The reason is I don't want to type all parameters in hand if there are many.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm using HTTP Proxy and here is the template mapping that I'm using. (It's actually the Method Request passthrough drop down).

```
#set($allParams = $input.params())
{
"body-json" : "$input.json('$')",
"params" : {
#foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
    #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
"$type" : {
    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
    "$paramName" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))"
        #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
}
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"stage-variables" : {
#foreach($key in $stageVariables.keySet())
"$key" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($stageVariables.get($key))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
},
"context" : {
    "account-id" : "$context.identity.accountId",
    "api-id" : "$context.apiId",
    "api-key" : "$context.identity.apiKey",
    "authorizer-principal-id" : "$context.authorizer.principalId",
    "caller" : "$context.identity.caller",
    "cognito-authentication-provider" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationProvider",
    "cognito-authentication-type" : "$context.identity.cognitoAuthenticationType",
    "cognito-identity-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityId",
    "cognito-identity-pool-id" : "$context.identity.cognitoIdentityPoolId",
    "http-method" : "$context.httpMethod",
    "stage" : "$context.stage",
    "source-ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp",
    "user" : "$context.identity.user",
    "user-agent" : "$context.identity.userAgent",
    "user-arn" : "$context.identity.userArn",
    "request-id" : "$context.requestId",
    "resource-id" : "$context.resourceId",
    "resource-path" : "$context.resourcePath"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231825&tstart=0) you must define all query string parameters explicitly. There is no passthrough support for query string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to specify each parameter in the template, you can just do something like this in the mapping template to pass any parameters:

```
  "queryParams": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }
```

Also in the API Gateway UI now you can just select "Method Request passthrough" in the "Generate Template" dropdown and it will create a template for you that passes headers and parameters and other things without the need to specify specific properties that you want to pass through.

Comment: added template in integration request as you said but it doesn't work. I still don't get query strings if I don't specify in URL query string parameters. I'm not using Lambda function.

Comment: Can you add your mapping template to your question?

Comment: I just added mapping template and it's actually the one in the drop down as you said. In the back end, I'm not getting any query strings in the request.

Comment: @jgranda2 I haven't used API Gateway with an HTTP backend before, but I think your going to have to read the request data from the HTTP request body that API Gateway submits to your backend instead of looking for parameters.